# Socket and connect call in while loop

Tags: c, sockets, while-loop

I need to loop a `connect` call in a while until a connection is actually done.

At first time I wrote this:

```
...
int sockFd;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

 memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr));
 serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(server->port));
 serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server->ip);

 if ((sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) perror("[-] Socket error!"), exit(-1);

 int checkValue;
 do {
  if((checkValue = connect(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr))) != 0) perror("[-] Connect error!");
 } while (checkValue != 0);
 ...
```

That seems logic to me, but when I execute the program, after the first "attempt" of the `connect`, the `connect` results in an "Invalid argument" error, but if I move the socket creation inside the loop, like this:

```
int sockFd;
 struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;

 memset(&serverAddr, '\0', sizeof(serverAddr)); 
 serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serverAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(server->port)); 
 serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server->ip); 

 int checkValue;
 do {
  if ((sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) perror("[-] Socket error!"), exit(-1);

  if((checkValue = connect(sockFd, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr))) != 0) {
   close(sockFd);
  }

 } while (checkValue != 0);
```

The program works well but the fact that I open and close so many sockets if the connection fails doesn't convince me.

Any advice?

Comment: You can't reconnect a TCP socket, even if the prior connect attempt failed. You have to close the socket and create a new one. You don't have any choice about this.

Comment: So my second version is right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct from that point of view, but it could do with a sleep, and some logging, and some differentiation between errors that are temporary and errors that are permanent, instead of just assuming the problem is external and will magically fix itself.

Comment: Sadly I can't use a sleep neither a logging function. For the errors of course they will be implemented! Thanks for the clarifications :)

Comment: Define 'can't use a logging function'. That is completely ridiculous.

Comment: Do you mean "create a log file" right? This is not "my" project, I need to follow some requests (university)

Comment: I didn't say either 'use a logging function' *or* 'create a log file'. I said 'do some logging'. Don't put words into my mouth, amd don't jump to conclusions. The user, if nobody else, deserves to know why you are spinning in this indiscriminate hard loop. Not even a university lecturer can downmark you for doing that.

Comment: @Serus `perror()` does logging, it writes a line of text to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding; `if ((sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) perror("[-] Socket error!"), exit(-1);
`  without braces, the `if()` statement only applies to the next statement.  Suggest:  `if ((sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) { perror("[-] Socket error!"); exit(-1); }`  Note: a comma separated sequence evaluates each expression, in left to right order, throwing away the result of each evaluation except the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to close this question, so:
my second proposal is correct.

Thanks to all for the suggestions!